# Someone approved an edit on one of my answers which changes its meaning

Tags: support

As the title says:

Someone approved an edit on one of my answers which changes its meaning.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9714118

Shouldn't there be a flag I can raise about this?

Comment: If you really wanted to - you could flag your post with a custom *other* flag and explain it... but for a one off - just roll it back and don't worry too much about it is probably the best course of action.

Comment: Okay, I rolled it back (I always knew that was an option) I just figured there was maybe a better way to handle this. specifically because that type of edit is invalid and shouldn't have been approved (not to mention the one who approved it also made the edit)

Comment: @InbarRose unless there becomes a pattern of behaviour outside of what appears to be a well intended but wrong edit - not much to worry about. Just rolling back in this case is the best way to handle it :)